# Initializing hash reference in perl

Tags: perl, hash, reference

The following Perl code prints `Value:0`. Is there a way to fix it other than by adding a dummy key to the hash before hash reference is passed to the subroutine ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my $Hash;

#$Hash->{Key1} = 1234;

Init($Hash);

printf("Value:%d\n",$Hash->{Key});

sub Init
{
    my ($Hash) = @_;
    $Hash->{Key}=10;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize an empty hash reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my $Hash = {};

Init($Hash);

printf("Value:%d\n",$Hash->{Key});

sub Init
{
    my ($Hash) = @_;
    $Hash->{Key}=10;
}
```

Comment: I would have voted for this if you explained why his original program didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Pretty new to this so I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3):

I know that an answer has already been accepted, but I figured it was worth explaining *why* the program acted this way in the first place.

The hash is not created until the second line of the `Init` function (`$Hash->{Key}=10`), which automatically creates a hash and stores a reference in the `$Hash` scalar. This scalar is local to the function, and has nothing to do with the `$Hash` variable in the body of the script.

This can be changed by modifying the way that the `Init` function handles its arguments:

```
sub Init {
    my $Hash = $_[0] = {};
    $Hash->{'Key'} = 10;
}
```

Comment: What is being passed to the subroutine if hash reference is not initialized ?

Comment: @Jean It's just sending an undefined scalar. Not a reference to anything.

Comment: Despite that I think assigning to `$_[0]` is a bad idea, why do you use `my $Hash` at all then in your answer? Wouldn't `$_[0} = { 'Key' => 10 }` do also?